Discrepancy between disc and shell method for volume around y-axis.
The question is:
Find the volume of revolution when the curve $y=x^2-1$, $1<x<5$, is rotated around the y-axis. Give your answer in terms of $\pi.$
Using the disk method, rearranging for x gives:
$x=\sqrt{y+1}$
$V=\int_0^{24} \pi(\sqrt {y+1})^2dy=\pi\int_0^{24} y+1dy=312\pi$
However, using the shell method, the volume is:
$V=\int_1^5 2\pi xy$ $dx = 288\pi$
I've done these calculation with my calculator so they should be correct. Where is the discrepancy coming from?

When computing using the shell method, you need to go all the way to the $y$-axis. You stop at $x=1$.
In the below image, your shell method computation is ignoring the part between the red lines. It's a cylinder of height 24 and radius 1, which gives the exact discrepancy of $24\pi$.


The instructions say $1\le x\le 5$

@user317176 That is true. However, OP is computing two different volumes. The shell method is only computing the volume corresponding to outside the red lines. The disk method is including the area inside the red lines.
Strictly speaking, a solid of revolution is what you get when you rotate an area around an axis, not a curve. Which leads to the ambiguity.

That makes a lot of sense! Thank you for the clarification!

Yes, you do account for the difference, but for what the question is asking, what the OP shows for the shell method is the correct value.  To do the disks, the OP should be deducting the inner radius from the integrand $\int_0^{24} (\sqrt {y+1})^2 - 1^2 \ dy = \int_0^{24} y \ dy$

When you do the disk method, you should doing washers, or exclude the cylinder when $|x|<1$  The volume of this cylinder is $24\pi.$

That is completely valid. My tectbook did not differentiate between these two.
